# WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus (WSO2 ESB) Proxy Service Schema Import

Tags: import, xsd, schema, wso2, esb

When I "virtualize" an endpoint using a proxy in WSO2 ESB I can read the following line in the resulting WSDL from WSO2:

When I paste the WSDL location (http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8283/services/Pin?wsdl) into soapUI 4.5 it cannot resolve related schema location up there with the XSD information.

It works fine when sending in the wsdl location (http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8283/services/Pin?wsdl) to the physical endpoint though.

The value of the schema location attribute looks odd, doesn't it? Any thoughts?

Regards,

Juan Pablo Garzón

Answer (score 0):

To access end point through ESB, you need to create proxy service using end point.

As well as You need to publish the wsdl file  when you create the proxy unless it will not populate the relevant interfaces from SOAP UI of operations in WSDL .

You can see how to publish WSDL in proxy services 
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Adding+a+Proxy+Service.

feel free to ask further help if i did not answer the your question.

Answer (score 0):

When creating proxy with a WSDL file, you have to provide the imported schemas also as resources. That is, you have to provide schemalocations to map with the path where those schemas are added..If you store your schemas in registry, you have to provide those paths when creating proxy